# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable - error appears when editing atributtes of an object

Tags: python

I'm trying to develop this code, for exercising Python with Object-oriented programming:

```
class Pessoa:

    def __init__(self, nome, sobrenome):
        self._nome = nome
        self._sobrenome = sobrenome

#getters
    @property
    def nome(self):
        return self._nome

    @property
    def sobrenome(self):
        return self._sobrenome

    @nome.setter
    def setNome(self, nome):
        self._nome = nome

    @sobrenome.setter
    def sobrenome(self, sobrenome):
        self._sobrenome = sobrenome

    def getNomeCompleto(self):
        return self._nome + " " + self._sobrenome

pessoa1 = Pessoa(None, None)

pessoa1.nome("Mário")
pessoa1.sobrenome("Lopes")
print(pessoa1.getNomeCompleto())
```

When I run the code, I always get this error, related to the line 'pessoa1.nome("Mário")':

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

And I have no idea how to solve it. What I'm trying to call is the setter method for nome.

Comment: `pessoa1.nome("Mário")` - you are trying to pass an argument to an object field. Call your setter, i.e. `pessoa1.setNome("Mário")` instead.

Comment: Oh, right. Will do that instead, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, your code tries to call the `nome` property on your class, which is initialized to `None`, raising the error you see.

Your setter for `nome` is currently incorrectly named - its name should match that of the property (getter):

```
@nome.setter                                                                
def nome(self, nome):                                                       
    self._nome = nome
```

After making that correction, the property value should instead be set using:

```
pessoa1.nome = "Mário"
```

This will then proceed via the setter method you defined.

In full:

```
pessoa1.nome = "Mário"
pessoa1.sobrenome = "Lopes"
print(pessoa1.getNomeCompleto())
```

Output:

```
Mário Lopes
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
pessoa1.nome("Mário")
```

You are trying to pass an argument to an object field. Call your setter instead, i.e.

```py
pessoa1.setNome("Mário")
```